# How to avoid the error "staticCFunction must take an unbound..." in Kotlin Native when a Kotlin callback function is called from C?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

This is a **general question** about callback functions, defined in Kotlin Native, called by C functions.

For argument's sake, let's say I'm trying to walk a directory in a filesystem recursively, using https://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw in *Kotlin Native*.
(I know there are other ways to do this, using other C functions, but that is not the core of this question.)

nftw() takes a function as a callback:

```
val directory = "//some/directory"
val callback = kotlinx.cinterop.staticCFunction {
            file: CPointer<ByteVar>?,
            stat: CPointer<stat>?,
            typeFlag: Int,
            b: CPointer<FTW>? ->

            val fileName = file?.toKString()
            println(fileName)
            val result = 0
            result
        }

val depth = 10
val flags = 0
platform.posix.nftw(directory, callback, depth, flags)
```

This works for listing files via "println()", but as as soon as the lambda contains any captured value, I get the following compiler error:

"kotlinx.cinterop.staticCFunction must take an unbound, non-capturing function or lambda".

My question is: is there any **recommended approach** on how to 
access any non-global state from such a callback?

I did come up with a nasty workaround using a global variable, so that's not what I'm looking for primarily. If there is a commonly accepted solution using @ThreadLocal or something else, please discuss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For native callbacks in general (not specific to `nftw`). The C function should accept a `void* userData` parameter and pass it to the callback when it is called. This allows you to pass local data to the callback, instead of global data.
This is the case even in C/C++.

For this particular case (regardless of language) there isn't really a way to do this without some global data (or JIT but let's not think about it). So any workaround would have to be nasty.

Using `@ThreadLocal` is a "reasonable nasty" solution.

`nftw` is just not a well designed C interface.